# How to make htaccess set file type on a particular file?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

So what I need to do is make it so a html file (without the html extension) gets viewed as an html file.

I had this line:

AddType application/msword mypage

but apparently that last argument in .htaccess only supports extensions. Is there a way to have that thing work on a particular file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<Files nosuffix>
DefaultType text/html
</Files>
```

References: [DefaultType](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#defaulttype) and [Files](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#files).